# Form Opens blank in form view

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a database system that logs calls for a department. All the calls for today are displayed on a main form in a list box. When a record is double clicked the call can be opened to view the information. This information is stored across two tables by a intermediate relationship.

When the form is opened in design view all the controls are visible. As soon as it goes to form view or a record is attempted to be opened, the form opens blank.

This has happened since i added the information from the second table. What has gone wrong?

Here is the query.

```
SELECT
TBL_CallsDB.ID, TBL_CallsDB.Agent_No, TBL_CallsDB.Agent_Name,
TBL_CallsDB.Call_Date, TBL_CallsDB.Call_Time, TBL_CallsDB.Caller_Type,
TBL_CallsDB.Call_Type, TBL_CallsDB.[Company Name], TBL_CallsDB.[Company Contact],
TBL_CallsDB.Caller_Name, TBL_CallsDB.Phone_No, TBL_CallsDB.Cell_No,
TBL_CallsDB.Fax_No, TBL_CallsDB.Email_Address, TBL_CallsDB.Address,
TBL_CallsDB.City, TBL_CallsDB.State, TBL_CallsDB.[Zip Code],
TBL_CallsDB.Details, TBL_CallsDB.Action_Resolve, TBL_CallsDB.Resolve_Date,
TBL_CallsDB.Resolved, TBL_CallsDB.Attachments, TBL_CallsDB.Status,
TBL_CallsDB.Memo, TBL_Units.Technology, TBL_Units.[Serial_No#],
TBL_Units.Model, TBL_Units.[Model_No#], TBL_Units.Unit_Type,
TBL_Units.Install_Date
FROM TBL_CallsDB
INNER JOIN TBL_Units ON TBL_CallsDB.Agent_No=TBL_Units.[Agent No];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "blank"? Do you mean that no records are displaying (in which case it's an issue with your query that you will have to investigate)? Or do you mean that all of the form design -- such as buttons, fields, etc. -- is missing (in which case it is either a problem with your form design settings or a malfunction in Access)?

Comment: All the buttons, text boxes and images are missing. However after taking out the second table and setting the query to the first table it worked. However the second table is needed.

Comment: Does that query return any rows when you test it in the Access query designer?

Comment: No it doesn't show anything. Since i removed the second table from the query it now shows all the information on the form. As soon as i have the second table is when it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine the values stored in `TBL_CallsDB.Agent_No` and `TBL_Units.[Agent No]`.  The query's join condition causes it to retrieve only those rows with matching values in `Agent_No` and `[Agent No]`.  But none of those existing values match, so the query returns no rows.

Comment: Now I feel a little stupid... When i checked the table on Units the Agent No is missing. If i add the agent Number in this should resolve my problem?